# how to open VS 2005 solution using VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

when i try to open a solution created before with VS 2005 in 2008 i got this error message in VS:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The application for project 'C:\myProject.csproj' is not installed.

### Make sure the application for the project type (.csproj) is installed.

### OK   Help

How to make VS 2008 open 2005 solutions? i missed to do something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message already suggests: Have you checked that all components of Visual Studio are installed? Re-run setup and make sure you choose the option *Complete*.

It is possible to install VS without support for C# projects, so that's probably what is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2008 should be able to open VS 2005 solutions without any problems (a wizard to convert your VS 2005 solution to a VS 2008 one should pop up). You probably have to give more information if you want a solution to your problem (for instance, is this VS Professional or Express?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the [Visual Studio Conversion Wizard.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467.aspx)

Comment: That is not a separate install, but part of the normal installation.

Comment: It is, but I've heard of people having problems with it before. I know I have. I heard about it earlier this month here: http://www.pchenry.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/86/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340138/why-is-visual-studio-not-able-to-open-csproj-files)** and after running the command in its answer in Run, everything worked